# load seccomp_export_bpf generated code into the kernel

Tags: kernel, bpf, seccomp

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_export_bpf.3.html how can I load the generated code into kernel? Which are possible use cases for this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I load the generated code into kernel?

If you're using `seccomp_export_bpf(const scmp_filter_ctx ctx, int fd)`, then you already have an initialized `scmp_filter_ctx` object, `ctx`, in which case, you can simply do:

```
int rc = seccomp_load(ctx);
```

No need to use `seccomp_export_bpf` to load the filter in the kernel.

> Which are possible use cases for this function?

I'm guessing `seccomp_export_bpf` is mostly useful when you want to keep a copy of your filter on disk for future use. For example, you could do (from [the man page example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_export_bpf.3.html)):

```
filter_fd = open("/tmp/seccomp_filter.bpf", O_WRONLY);
if (filter_fd == -1) {
     rc = -errno;
     goto out;
}

rc = seccomp_export_bpf(ctx, filter_fd);
```

To then load that exported filter in the kernel you could do:

```
char filter[4096];
int length = read(0, filter, 4096);
if (length < 0) {
    goto out;
}
struct sock_fprog bpf_prog = {
    .len = length / sizeof(struct sock_filter),
    .filter = filter,
};
rc = prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER, &bpf_prog);
```

Comment: Hi, I think it should be `.len = length / sizeof(struct sock_filter)` and there is a syntax error in line 2.